# How do I post large data through an AJAX call (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery's ajax functionality to update data from a web form (ASP.NET MVC).  Part of the data comes from a text area, and while is not a huge amount of data, can easily be more than 2 KB.

It seems that jQuery ajax puts all data into the query string, hence causing IIS to reject the URL, hence breaking the call.  Is it possible to add data to a POST request using the ajax model under jQuery, rather than having everything in the query string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [$.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

e.g

```
$.post(someUrl, { textData: $('#someInput').val() } );
```

$.post is just a simple wrapper around $.ajax.

```
$.ajax({ type :"post", 
         data : { textData: $('#someInput').val() },
         url : someUrl
      });
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes; according to [jQuery's documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax), you can use `jQuery.post` to POST data.

If you want to post an existing form, use:

```
var form = $("#myform"); // or whatever
$.post(form.get()[0].action, form.serialize(), function(data) {
    // data received
}, "xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FormData:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('filename', filename);
formData.append('data', data);
$.ajax({
    url: "FileUploadServlet",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false});
```